# Which Christian groups or denominations believe in modern-day Christophanies?

Tags: denomination-survey, spirituality, supernatural, christophany

The Bible records several instances of *Christophanies*, i.e., occasions where Jesus appeared and/or spoke to his disciples after having ascended to heaven. Probably the most well-known example is Paul's encounter with Jesus when he was on his way to Damascus ([Acts 9:3-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+9%3A3-6&version=ESV)), but we also have the conversation between Ananias and the Lord ([Acts 9:10-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+9%3A10-16&version=ESV)) and Stephen's vision of Jesus at the right hand of the Father ([Acts 7:54-56](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+7%3A54-56&version=ESV)). And, of course, how to forget John's powerful encounter with Jesus on Patmos, an event that was recorded in detail in the book of Revelation.

Which Christian groups or denominations believe these sorts of encounters with Jesus still happen today?

Comment: When you get away from the defining doctrines of a particular theological movement it gets very hard to make any valid generalisations. Cessationism is about the types of spiritual gifts still active today. It doesn't directly imply anything about Jesus speaking directly to people, so I don't think this is likely to be answerable. Even if it could be answered, would it be a useful answer? The only answer you'd get would be the dominant position on an unrelated topic, so there wouldn't necessarily be any causal link between it and cessationism.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I asked the question inspired by the success I had with a similar question about contemporary revelations from the Holy Spirit (see the last edit).

Comment: I think there's a difference because hearing the Holy Spirit speak is associated with the gift of prophecy, more than hearing Jesus speak is.

Comment: @curiousdannii - good point. I turned the question into a denomination survey to make it more general.

Answer (score 2):

**Which Christian groups or denominations believe in modern-day Christophanies?**

Both Catholicism, Eastern Orthodoxy and the  Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints claim to have Christophanies.

A Christophany being an appearance or non-physical manifestation of Christ. Traditionally the term refers to visions of Christ after his ascension, such as the bright light of the conversion of Paul the Apostle.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christophany), the following Christophanies have occurred:

> - Saint Jerome is believed to have had a precise vision of the Trinity, as is illustrated by Andrea del Castagno.
> - Magdalena de Pazzi was a mystic who claimed several Christophanies about the Trinity.
> - Lúcia dos Santos of Fatima claimed to have seen Jesus in the Trinity in Tui in 1926.
> - Mary Faustina Kowalska claimed to have had recorded her visions of Jesus.
> - Joseph Smith claimed to have seen both Jesus Christ and God the Father in an event known as the First Vision.

The visions of Christ to [St. Faustina Kowalska](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faustina_Kowalska) are the most well known Christophanies of the modern day times. I am sure more exist.

Answer (score 0):

### The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints

Firmly continuationist, it shouldn't surprise that LDS appear here.

Multiple modern-day Christophanies recorded in Doctrine & Covenants and The Pearl of Great Price.

- The First Vision ([Joseph Smith - History 1:17](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/pgp/js-h/1?lang=eng))  (Joseph Smith)
- Appearance in the Kirtland Temple ([D&C 110:1-10](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/110?lang=eng)) (Joseph Smith + Oliver Cowdery)
- In a vision regarding the Afterlife ([D&C 76:14-24](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/76?lang=eng)) (Joseph Smith + Sidney Rigdon)

There is explicit doctrine that Jesus can and does appear to people ([D&C 130:3](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/130?lang=eng))

Other personal appearances where there is recorded testimony:

- [Lorenzo Snow](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/friend/1993/08/lorenzo-snow-and-the-sacred-vision?lang=eng)

Note: LDS believe the Second Coming is still in the future, none of these appearances should be confused with the Second Coming.